# Repeat jquery Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$("#like_answer_button").removeAttr("disabled");
$('#like_answer_button').click(function(e)
    {
        var id = $(this).closest('.box').data('id');
        var url = "https://www.sdkwf.de/jquery/good_answer.php?answer_user=" + id;          
        var val = parseInt($("#like_answer_button").val(), 10);
        $.post(url,{op:"<?php echo $ask; ?>"},function(data)
        {
            $("#status").html("");
            val = val+1;
            $("#like_answer_button").val(val);
            $("#like_answer_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#like_answer_button").css("background-image","url(https://www.sdkwf.de/img/icon.png)");
        })
    });
```

Any idea how I can make this script work if repeated in PHP (while) for many different buttons with this code?

```
<div class="box" data-id="'.$id.'">
<input type="submit" class="like" name="like_answer_button" value="10" id="like_answer_button" />
```

It only works for the first button/input, but the other ones do not work. I guess because like_answer_button is reserved for first one?

Comment: Id's have to be unique, use a class instead.

Comment: And use `$(this)` within the click handler to refer to the clicked element

Comment: But how do you want to submit the class to the script? E.g. class="button_$1" but in the script you need to hardcode $("#like_answer_button")

Comment: Class is the __same__ for __all__ buttons.

Comment: I guess I have to loop the full script then for each button. $("#like_answer_button_$ID")... so on.

Comment: Wait you have multiple id's use classes and $(this) should work fine what is your main problem is id not being sent properly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are already using `$(this)` for your `closest('.box')` call. That is a reference to the clicked `like_answer_button`. Capture it in a var, and use it in the post callback:

```
$("input[type='submit'].like").click(function(e)
    {
        var button = $(this);
        var id = button.closest('.box').data('id');
        var url = "https://www.sdkwf.de/jquery/good_answer.php?answer_user=" + id;          
        var val = parseInt(button.val(), 10);

        $.post(url, { op: "<?php echo $ask; ?>" }, function(data)
        {
            $("#status").html("");
            val = val + 1;
            button.val(val);
            button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            button.css("background-image","url(https://www.sdkwf.de/img/icon.png)");
        })
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML - don't repeat the same id for inputs. ensure names and ids are unique if you need them.

```
<div class="box" data-id="'.$id.'">
<input type="submit" class="like" value="10" />

<div class="box" data-id="'.$id.'">
<input type="submit" class="like" value="11" />

<div class="box" data-id="'.$id.'">
<input type="submit" class="like" value="12" />
```

JS - Use a class selector instead of a specific element id in your javascript

```
$('.like').click(function(e)
{
    var id = $(this).closest('.box').data('id');
    var url = "https://www.sdkwf.de/jquery/good_answer.php?answer_user=" + id;          
    var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    $.post(url,{op:"<?php echo $ask; ?>"},function(data)
    {
        $("#status").html("");
        val = val+1;
        $(this).val(val);
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(this).css("background-image","url(https://www.sdkwf.de/img/icon.png)");
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
        // click handler
        jQuery('.like').on('click', function(e){
          // get the value of the input   
          var val = jQuery(e.currentTarget).val();
    
          // find the element that contains the data-id and do something to it
          jQuery('[data-id="'+ val +'"]').hide();
    
        });
```

```html
<?php $iterator = 0; ?>
    
    <?php foreach($array as $key=>$value): ?>
    
          <div class="box" data-id="<?php echo 'target-'.$iterator; ?>">
          <input type="submit" class="like" value="<?php echo 'target-'.$iterator; ?>" />
      <?php $iterator++; ?>
    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```